# Rails: build method breaks loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, insert, has-many

I'm was trying to add multiple objects like so:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interests
  ...

  def add_interests(interest_hashes)
    interest_hashes.each do |interest|
      Rails.logger.debug "person.apply_interests: interest: #{interest.inspect}"
      interests.build(:name => interest.name, :category => interest.category)
    end
    save!
  end
  ...
end
```

However in the log when calling `<some person>.add_interests(<some hashes>)` all I see is the first hash - no error or exception. If I remove the build method the loop works as expected.

1. What is happening when calling the build method?
2. What's a better way to achieve what I'm trying?

**Edit:**

`interest_hashes.inspect` output example:

```
[{"category"=>"Interest", "name"=>"Formula One"}, {"category"=>"Musical instrument", "name"=>"Guitar"}]
```

Comment: The parameter of the function is called `interests_hash`, you use an instance variable (not the parameter) instead, you iterate as if an array, and it contains ... mmm objects? Could you please clarify what `interests_hash` contains?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Made some mistakes editing and renaming stuff. Renamed the `interests_hash`to ìnterest_hashes`, which contains an array of hashes. That wasn't what causes the loop to break however (the original code is a bit different).

Comment: My guess is that you're getting a NoMethodError when calling `name` on `interest`, but it's not being shown to your for some reason. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a NoMethodError when calling `name` and `category` on `interest`, since hashes are accessed using the `[]` method. Replace

```
interest.name
```

with

```
interest["name"]
```

Or use an [Struct](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Struct.html), which may be preferable.

Comment: How? Have you monkey-patched the Hash class?

Comment: Thank you, that actually was the problem. I tried changing it, but at first nothing has changed, until I saw the same mistake in the `if`-condition (which was not included here in my question xD)

Comment: And just to make the confusion complete: http://rubydoc.info/github/intridea/omniauth/master/OmniAuth/AuthHash I can access the OmniAuth::AuthHash that way `oauth.uid`. That's what lead me to think it was possible with Hashes in general.

Comment: This is because it inherits from [`Hashie::Mash`](https://github.com/intridea/hashie#mash)

Comment: Thanks a lot, learning new stuff every 5 minutes. I would up vote your comments, if I could.